# openssl hangs on server

Tags: debian, curl, wget, openssl

I have a problem on the server. Commands wget, curl and dependent commands are not working when a request is via 443 port.

Commands hangs on 2-3 minutes and after just say "time out":

```
# curl -v google.com:443
* About to connect() to google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 2a00:1450:4009:806::200e...
```

and

```
# openssl s_client -connect facebook.com:443
```

What is happening?

This is network interface configuration `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet6 auto
iface eth0 inet static
address 111.22.333.44/24
gateway 111.22.333.1
```

Comment: is this from debian?

Comment: Please add extra debugging to the question besides the elementary data of the IP addresses of your interfaces.

Comment: Yes, it is debian 7.

Comment: Rui F Ribeiro, there are 57 rows in interface response by command `ip addr show
` Some of rows can be sensitive and I am  afraid if i give you info with replaced mac addresses and ip addresses it could not help to investigate. Can you say what can I find in response exactly? I have some repeated rows with minimum difference. Thanks.

Comment: You are having routing/firewalling problems *when* using IPv6, supposing you have IPv6 decently configure. Without you sharing your addresses, we cannot tell.

Comment: May be this can help: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`